# FPDF : PDF downloads automatically in mobile browsers in .php extension (Not supported)

Tags: php, android, pdf, mobile, fpdf

I have developed a dynamic PDF by using FPDF Library. Everything works fine in computer, but in mobile, the PHP file starts download and also the download is cancelled automatically.

This is a sample coding

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

If I save this file as "sample.php" and view in computer, the PDF is open without any error with the output "Hello World". But if I view the page in any android browsers (Google chrome, Firefox for Android, Android Browser), the file "sample.php" is downloaded instead of viewing the PDF file.

Comment: I have checked that the latest android devices work well with FPDF but the earlier android versions like Kitkat has the problem. Any possibilities to rectify this? 

Actually the PDF should be open in browser instead of downloading the PHP file.

Comment: PDF still downloads in mobile browsers in .php extension, I tried below ans not working

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this browser is exceptionally picky with the headers you send. If you have blanks in your Content-Type headers between each element, Android will ignore them.

```
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

header('Content-type: application/download;filename="example.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
echo $pdf->Output('S');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf->Output('I','name_file.pdf');
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by some explanation. Please see [answer]